# make http request inside google app engine, python

Tags: google-app-engine, http, webapp2

I want to send a request from my google app engine to another server, currently i am using python and Webapp2 framework.
I think it should to be similar to curl library in php !
How could i do that ?thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import urllib2

url = "http://www.google.com/"
try:
  result = urllib2.urlopen(url)
  doSomethingWithResult(result)
except urllib2.URLError, e:
  handleError(e)
```

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/

Comment: thank you very much :) I can use this to connect to gcm server ,that is right?

Comment: np. Don't know much about gcm, but if you can interact with it over http then yes.

Answer (score 2):

There is also the urlfetch service.  urllib2 uses this, so for simple tasks urlfetch is usually a little easier.  However urlfetch is specific to appengine, so that is a reason not to use it if you want portable code.

See docs https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/